# Bubblesort Struct Array with Enumerated Direction/Type

Tags: c++, bubble-sort, enumerated-types

I have a function sort, being passed an Array of structs.

Structs contain strings.

```
struct studentStruct {                                                                                                                      
  string firstName;
  string lastName;
  int grade;
  float GPA;
};
```

I'm passing this array of structs to a sorting function, as well as 2 enumerated types.

```
enum sortField {eFirstName, eLastName, eGrade, eGPA};                                                                                                   
enum sortDirection {eAscending, eDescending};
```

Now, I have to use Bubblesort and a compData function, so;

```
void sort( studentStruct s[], enum sortField field, int length, sortDirection d)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < length - 1 - i; j++)
        {
          if(compData(s[j], s[j+1], field, d) == true)
            {
              swap(s[j], s[j+1]);
              cout << "SWAP" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
bool compData( studentStruct s1, studentStruct s2,  sortField field, sortDirection direction)
{
  switch(field)
    {
    case eFirstName:
      {
        string f1 = s1.firstName;
        string f2 = s2.firstName;
        switch(direction)
          {
          case eAscending:
            {
              if(f2 < f1)
                return true;
            }
          case eDescending:
            {
              if(f2 > f1)
                return true;
            }
          }
      }
    }
}
```

So; I pass sort my Array of `Structs s[]`, it calls `compData` to decide whether or not to switch `s[j]` and `s[j+1]`. `compData` looks at the enumerated values to decide how we are comparing `s[j]` and `s[j+1]`, selects to sort on `eFirstName`, `eAscending`, and sort accordingly.

But in actuality, I pass `sort(s[], eFirstName, 10, eAscending)` and I'm getting an improperly sorted mess. For 5 inputs of `M, I, K, O, N,` I'm getting out
`N, O, K, I, M;` its just flipping the array.

Comment: Aren't you getting a compiler warning for that `compData` function that's not returning something on all code paths?

Comment: @Blaze I have the rest of the switch cases in my actual program, but didnt feel the need to copy paste them over to the thread to avoid a wall of text. I have a switch(field){ case eLastName: ... etc, with the same copy/paste if statement from case eFirstName

Comment: Silly question: if you're passing 5 inputs, why are you passing `10` for the length? And fyi, an actual, *real* `main` with your test case and statically coded data demonstrating the problem would relieve you of questions like that.

Comment: Not only is the `compData` function missing your other cases, it also has no possible `return false` path for the case you _did_ show. Maybe you removed a bit too much?

Comment: Also, fyi, your `compData` returns true if the first element s1 should appear *before* the second, s2. While this is reasonable, the caller has to pass the correct arguments in the correct order. In your call site, your passing `s[j]` and `s[j+1]` respectively. If `true` is returned, they're *already* in the correct order. No swap should take place. Your arguments are backward. That call should be `if (compData(s[j+1], s[j], field, d))`. A true return then means the element at the `j+1` index should come before the element at `j`, and a swap is warranted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison function is mostly missing, but the parts that are there suggest you have no path to ever return a definitive `false`, which is mandatory for a proper comparator.

Second, you call order of arguments is wrong. The "right" side argument should be *first*, the "left" side second. if the comparator answers true, they're in the wrong order and should be swapped.

Addressing both of those (and granting you an improved bubblesort with early exit detection on already-sorted sequences), the result functions as intended:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

enum sortField {eFirstName, eLastName, eGrade, eGPA};
enum sortDirection {eAscending, eDescending};

struct studentStruct {
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    int grade;
    float GPA;
};

bool compData( studentStruct s1, studentStruct s2, sortField field, sortDirection direction)
{
    bool result = false;

    switch(field)
    {
        case eFirstName:
            switch(direction)
            {
                case eAscending:
                    result = s1.firstName < s2.firstName;
                    break;

                case eDescending:
                    result = s2.firstName < s1.firstName;
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case eLastName:
            switch(direction)
            {
                case eAscending:
                    result = s1.lastName < s2.lastName;
                    break;

                case eDescending:
                    result = s2.lastName < s1.lastName;
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case eGrade:
            switch(direction)
            {
                case eAscending:
                    result = s1.grade < s2.grade;
                    break;

                case eDescending:
                    result = s2.grade < s1.grade;
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case eGPA:
            switch(direction)
            {
                case eAscending:
                    result = s1.GPA < s2.GPA;
                    break;

                case eDescending:
                    result = s2.GPA < s1.GPA;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }

    return result;

}

void sort( studentStruct s[], enum sortField field, int length, sortDirection d)
{
    bool swapped = true;
    while (swapped && length-- > 0)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int i=0; i<length; ++i)
        {
            if (compData(s[i+1], s[i], field, d))
            {
                std::cout << "SWAP" << '\n';
                std::swap(s[i+1], s[i]);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    studentStruct students[] = { {"M"}, {"I"}, {"K"}, {"O"}, {"N"} };
    sort(students, eFirstName, 5, eAscending);

    for (auto const& s : students)
        std::cout << s.firstName << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
SWAP
SWAP
SWAP
I
K
M
N
O
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added `return false` for the `else` part of the conditional statements in `compData` and it works as expected.

```
switch(direction)
{
    case eAscending:
    {
        if(f2 < f1)
            return true;
        else    
            return false;
    }
    case eDescending:
    {
        if(f2 > f1)
            return true;
        else    
            return false;
    }
}
```

See online [demo](https://ideone.com/l6gqD9).